Replace require with import in typescript
I am developing an app in NodeJS, and need to use old packages.
The problem is that in their instructions the usage suggested is with require:
var xxx = require("xxx");

but I get an ELSint error Do not use "require".
If I simply replace require with import I get:
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module xxx.

What would be the correct solution for this problem?

There might be a problem with the old package not having a typescript declaration files (.d.ts). There have been created type declarations for some packages, you may try installing it by running the following in the command line:
npm i --save-dev @types/xxx

(Replace xxx with the name of the package.)
Then simply import the package as usual using import:
import xxx from "xxx";

Or import only some functions:
import { someFunc } from "xxx";

Hope it helps!

you can use dynamic imports
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url); // Why? relative to absolute path within a module (Browser / server)

const xxx = require('xxx');

BTW, have you tried lazy loading? await import('xxx')

As a follow up to Libertas's answer, if @types/[package] does not exist, then you can resolve this error by declaring the module in a typescript declaration file (with a .d.ts extension).
// index.d.ts
declare module 'xxx';

Note that when you import the module, it will be typed as any unless you add your own types to the module in the declarations file.
// index.d.ts
declare module 'xxx' {
    // your custom types
    export function getValue(): string
}

